# node version difference between mac and linux

Tags: node.js, macos

on my mac, key node -v, I get "v6.2.2", on centos, I get "v0.10.36", on centos, I keys "uname -a", I get "Linux VM_80_24_centos 3.10.0-123.el7.x86_64 #1 SMP Mon Jun 30 12:09:22 UTC 2014 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux", how can I understand the difference between two version num.

Comment: How are you installing them? What makes you think they _should_ be the same?

Answer (score 0):

It seems like one is node version and another is npm version. You might executed the different commands.

To check node version:

## node -v

will give 'v6.2.2'.

To check npm version:

## npm -v

will give 'v0.10.36'.